# How scrollbar width is calculated in plugins ( scrollbar plugins)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to create a small scrollbar plugin for my project. So, I referred some plugins and what they did is, created the horizontal and vertical scrollbar by creating a div and assigned top, right, left, bottom properties. But now i ran into a problem.

How to set the width for vertical scrollbar and height for horizontal scrollbar?

See the attached image.

[image]

The outer div height is 600px and the image height is 720 and the scrollbar height is 222px.

So, how they calculated the height of the scrollbar?

Guys, maybe its a simple one, but i cant figure it out. Help with that guys.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you probably want the height of the vertical scrollbar thumb/grip and the width of the horizontal one's thumb/grip not the other way around...

Comment: Yep...how can i calculate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll size (s) is usually directly proportional to the size of the displayed area (a) in relation to the size of the content (c).

If you consider the maximum size of the scrollbar to be the same as the size of the displayed area then you're left with the following formula for size:
s = a / c * a = a * a / c
Or if you want your scroll to have a different max size the formula becomes s = a / c * maxs = a * maxs / c

In your case the div height is actually 400px not 600, so you have 400 / 720 * 400 = 222.(2) which you can round to an integer if you want.